How to get the screen coordinates of a point on a plot in MATLAB?
As the question states, I would like to obtain the screen coordinates of a given point on a plot. I am not interested in getting the plot-dependent coordinates of a point selected by the user (I would use ginput for that like in this answer).
Instead, I would like to return the coordinates in the [0,1] units of a given point on a plot (e.g. I create a figure with figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])).
The reason I want to do this is an extension of this answer, which I reproduce the code hereunder. I would like to determine posSmall{1} such that the location of the axes matches certain coordinates in the graph. For instance, I would like to put the first small axis such that its bottom left corner is at (40,-8) on the graph on the left.
%# sample data
x = 1:100;
left = randn(100,1);
right = cumsum(rand(100,1)-0.5);

%# build axes positions
hBig = [subplot(121) subplot(122)];         %# create subplots
posBig = get(hBig, 'Position');             %# record their positions
delete(hBig)                                %# delete them
posSmall{1} = [0.275 0.63 0.16 0.24];
posSmall{2} = [0.717 0.63 0.16 0.24];

%# create axes (big/small)
hAxB(1) = axes('Position',posBig{1});
hAxB(2) = axes('Position',posBig{2});
hAxS(1) = axes('Position',posSmall{1});
hAxS(2) = axes('Position',posSmall{2});

%# plot
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
plot(hAxB(1), x, left, 'b');
plot(hAxB(2), x, right, 'b');
plot(hAxS(1), x, left, 'r');
plot(hAxS(2), x, right, 'r');

%# set axes properties
set(hAxB, 'XLim',[1 100], 'YLim',[-10 10]);
set(hAxS , 'Color','none', 'XAxisLocation','top', 'YAxisLocation','right');

For this to work, I would need to determine the position of the point (40,-8) in the first graph and set posSmall{1} accordingly.
Thanks in advance.

Have a look at the answer to this question. He is trying to do the same thing that you want and the answer explains the coordinate conversion necessary.

Note that the approach referred to by Hoki seems to require that the big axis uses linear scale, that is, 'XScale' and 'YScale' equal to 'linear'
